# Empty position in dependance the heads of two bones...how?

Tags: animation

Attached there is a (not working) example, of what I try to acchieve:
There is a rig (sort of...) with two bones: bone_L and bone_R.
While animating the bones I want the empty to be positioned between
the two heads of those bones - as it would be, if one would go
into edit mode (position of the bones preserved) select both heads,
then "cursor to selected", the out of edit mode select the empty
and "selected to cursor". But constantly applied while animating
the bones Bone_L and Bone_R.

How can I acchieve this?
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please provide some context and explanation about your issue, don't force users to download your file. See [What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “*How do I do this?*”](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this) Add images illustrating your current setup and the issues you are encountering

Comment: How can I add an image? Blendexchange only allows blend files....

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using two copy location constraints on the empty, but setting the second one to 50%.